# How do I get a User RoleClaim in a single command in asp.net identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using roleclaims in my application that's all set up and working, but I want to do something like this

`result = await User.HasRoleClaim("ClaimName")`

where this `result` is a boolean **true** if any role the user is in has that claim and **false** if no role they are in does not have that claim.

Am I missing something because I can't see a response to this anywhere, not even on the Microsoft pages so I'm guessing it can't be done. That functionality doesn't seem to exist. Using rolemanager and/or usermanager I can get/set roles, claims and even roleclaims, but I can't find a way to get user.roleclaims (or similar).

I can construct my own methods to do this, but just wanted to ask/check if what I want to do is possible before I go off down a rabbit hole

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `RoleClaim`? Do you mean `User.IsInRole` or `User.HasClaim`? If not, you need to implement your own method to achieve this.

Comment: All my claims are `RoleClaims` so the users get them by being in a role. I tried `User.HasClaim` but it always failed. I read a load of Identity articles which said it should work (the articles all seem based on `UserClaims`) but it just didn't work so I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: @TaoZhou. `.IsInRole` and .`HasClaim` both do exactly as I wanted, thanks loads. I had to do some reading to confirm what I wanted to do. It's just a colleague had done something similar elsewhere but for some reason, they made it much more complicated.

Comment: Hi, @djack109, Can you please share your finding by providing answer?